# Creating Makefile to compile 2 file at once

Tags: c

```
If I compile by hand, my code should be
gcc image.c -c
gcc stego.c -c
gcc image.c stego.c -o Stego
```

Then I tried to create a Makefile to compile everything at once. However, it isn't successful. I don't know what is wrong with this. Could you please give an adivse.

```
GCC=gcc
all:Stegonew
Stegonew:stego.o image.o
        ${GCC} stego.o image.o -o Stegonew
stego.o: stego.c image.h
        ${GCC} stego.c -c
image.o:image.c
        ${GCC} image.c -c
clean:
      rm *.o Stegonew
```

Comment: What errors are you seeing? And you *are* using tabs (not spaces) for the command lines, right? (`        ${GCC} stego.c`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got the error message : " Don't know how to make target Stegonew". @PaulRoub

Comment: Have you tried `make -j2`?

Comment: @SunnyTrinh You should also answer the part of Paul Roub's question regarding whether you're using tabs or spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
notice that all indented lines are actual a single leading tab char
lots more could be added to this makefile to yield a more flexable result
but the following should do the job

* give full path use ':' so only evaluated once
* following path value is for linux
GCC := /usr/bin/gcc
RM  := /usr/bin/rm

* tell make that certain targets will not produce a file of the same name
.PHONY: all clean

* this target will be performed if user only enters 'make'
all:Stegonew

* link the executable, 
* are any libraries needed? 
* if so, set path by: '-Lpath' set library by '-llibname'
* where libname is missing leading 'lib' chars and trailing '.so' characters
* of actual library name
Stegonew:stego.o image.o
        ${GCC} stego.o image.o -o Stegonew

* compile the stego.c file, 
* '-I.' says to look for source code line: #include "image.h" in current directory
* '-c' says compile only
stego.o: stego.c image.h
        ${GCC} -c stego.c -o stego.o -I.

* compile the image.c file, 
* '-I.' says to look for source code line: #include "image.h" in current directory
* '-c' says compile only
image.o:image.c image.h
        ${GCC} -c image.c -o image.o -I.

* target for removing the re-producable files
* '-f' forces the removal without asking user for approval
clean:
        $(RM) -f *.o Stegonew
```